# Python Portable Install gives error

Tags: python

i am starting to use Databases and am using MariaDB, Got that ready, but i want Python integration so i can get started on the program.

I have downloaded PyMySQL-0.7.10.tar.gz from the official python website
and have unzipped and have navigated an Command Prompt to there using `cd (dir)`.

My command is:

```
"G:\Python\Portable\Portable Python 3.2.5.1\App\python.exe" setup.py install
```

(Yes, i am on Windows 10 and i am using Portable Python. This is because i learn it at school but also want to be able to work at it at home.)

The error it returns is the following:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "setup.py", line 4, in <module>
    version_tuple = __import__('pymysql').VERSION
  File "C:\Users\Natan Samuel Geldorp.Remytop-PC\Downloads\PyMySQL-0.7.10\pymysql\__init__.py", line 28, in <module>
    from .converters import escape_dict, escape_sequence, escape_string
  File "C:\Users\Natan Samuel Geldorp.Remytop-PC\Downloads\PyMySQL-0.7.10\pymysql\converters.py", line 60
    _escape_table[0] = u'\\0'
                            ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Does anyone know how to fix this?

-Natan

Comment: You need a newer Python version - 3.2 is pretty outdated and there the `u` prefix is not allowed (it is allowed again since 3.3, or in 2.x)

Comment: Yes but there isnt a portable version for that version of Python

Comment: Also the PyMySQL website states that you need Python >= 2.6 or >= 3.3 (and the Portable Python website states that it is no longer being developed and you should switch to an alternative)

Comment: (See my previous comment about Portable Python) - also why do you want a Portable version? Python is not a huge installation (apparently [WinPython](http://winpython.github.io/) is a portable version, but I still don't understand why you don't just install the official CPython distribution)

Comment: As i said, cant install at school and want to be able to use at school aswell as at home as i am begging at my maths teacher everyday for some more python lessons because thats where i learn it. And please write this as an answer so i can mark it as the solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As requested, as an answer:

You need a newer Python version, in 3.0 to 3.2 the `u` prefix was forbidden, it was allowed again in version 3.3.

Since [Portable Python](http://portablepython.com/) is no longer being developed (according to their site) you need to pick an alternative. One suggested on the site is [WinPython](http://winpython.github.io/).

(Also the [PyMySQL](https://github.com/PyMySQL/PyMySQL) site states that the minimum required Python versions are either >= 2.6 or >= 3.3)

Comment: Thank You very much